# Please re-open GPL licensing question 192299

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I have suggested an edit to [Can I use GNU source in my iOS app?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/192299) replacing the confusing use of "GNU source" and "GNU license" with "GPL license" throughout.

I believe this should clarify this rather straightforward question, without needing to further disambiguate which version of the GPL license the OP is asking about.

I am happy to suggest further edits based on feedback here!

Comment: Would you put up an answer here so we can see what sort of straightforward answer might be needed? Perhaps I’m missing the obvious

Comment: I'll do that - in the meantime, see my comment on the original question

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for asking on meta for a discussion.

Your edit is pretty minor and I would put the iTunes connect tag back in since that’s the overall “service” that apple offers which makes this on topic here.

My hesitation to reopen is this second question - it needs to be gone or stated as a fact with references so it doesn’t look like there’s a side question that needs to be addressed first.

> Second, iOS does not allow 3rd party dynamic libraries, which means, to my understanding, you can't legally combine GPL and non-GPL code in one iOS app

What sort of answer would you be looking to add @d3vid? This seems much more suited for Stack Overflow since we are not at all a place to discuss code level questions and the license that governs code level decisions seems to be far more apt for developers.

I do get that we could have an answer that literally reviews the license / EULA / developer agreement and explains if Apple mentions anything about license directly. From Apple’s perspective, they may not even say anything except insist the developer is responsible for owning and licensing everything they use to sell.

Comment: As noted with vlc Apple did not complain - and there are vlc apps in the store now - it was a contributer who complained

Answer (score 0):

You have improved the question - it is now broader and my answer still holds as it is about GPL.

However you have not changed the reasons others voted it as off topic it is still a licensing question.

Also how do your comments differ from my answer?

Comment: regarding licensing, are *all* licensing questions off topic? I saw an issue raised about jurisdiction which I don't think applies

Comment: I'm struggling to see how it's too broad, should it specify GPL 2 or GPL 3?

Comment: last point (thanks for your feedback) I addressed the dependency issue in my second comment

Comment: I realise now that I could probably suggest an edit to your answer, I'll give that a whirl and see what you think